# XML : cut xmlns on MacOs

Tags: php, xml, macos, xml-namespaces

I have a script which generate xml.

On my computer php 5.3.6, Ubuntu 11.10, libxml 2.7.8

On other computer php 5.2.10, libxml 2.7.3, MacOS 10.7.3

And on my computer xml was generated correct with xmlns attribute.
In other xml almost same as need but without xmlns attribute.

P.S. I have an array of attribute and in cycle generate xml and add attributes from array.
Please help.

Comment: No code? No sample output? How can we help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem in php version. Must be a 5.3.6